# How Collection copy function works in java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand how Java Generic works. Here is the problems.

```
  public static void main(String args[]){

    List<Object> obj = Arrays.<Object>asList(23,"456",56.89);
    List<Integer> intb = new ArrayList<>();
    intb.add(234);
    intb.add(345);
    Collections.copy(obj,intb);
    for(Object d : obj){
        System.out.println(d);
    }

   }
```

This will work fine.But I implemented my own copy function like this

```
   public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> des,List<? extends T> scr){
    for(T f : scr){
        des.add(f);
    }
  }
```

Then I used copy(obj,intb) instead of Collections.copy(obj,intb). Then I am getting errors. I don't understand why,But I know "? extends T" means  any type that is a subtype of T and "? super T" means any type that is a supertype of T.

Comment: Tell us what the errors are.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
 at ListTest.copy(ListTest.java:21)
 at ListTest.main(ListTest.java:13)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *add* anything to this [fixed-length list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

```
List<Object> obj = Arrays.<Object>asList(23,"456",56.89);
```

You can only *set* new values to its elements (which is what `Collections.copy()` does). See also the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

What you probably intended to do was this:

```
List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(23,"456",56.89));
```

Comment: Interesting, if it's true. This would not be a problem in C#; the resulting list would be variable-length.  A list is a list and an array is an array, in other words.

Comment: @LukasEder technically a fixed size list

Answer (score 2):

Well, a little bit late, but why your compiler complained about your code is not only because you used a fixed-size (immutable) `List` as a parameter in your `copy` method.

```
List<Object> obj = Arrays.<Object>asList(23, "456", 56.89);
Collections.copy(obj, intb);
```

It is also because of your (`copy`) method declaration.

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> des,List<? extends T> scr) {
```

The declaration above has two lists with wildcards. When you use wildcard type `<?>`, you give message to the compiler that you are ignoring the type information. Whenever you pass arguments to a generic type, the java compiler tries to infer the type of the passed argument as well as the type of the generics and to justify the type safety. Now,(in your copy method) you are trying to use the `add()` method to insert an element in the list. Since des(your destination list) doesn't know the exact type of object it holds, it is risky to add elements to it. Generics was introduced in the language to ensure type safety in the first place. So you can not use methods like add that modifies the object. I hope the default implementation of the `copy` method in the `java.util.Collections` will help clarify it.

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
        int srcSize = src.size();
        if (srcSize > dest.size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Source does not fit in dest");

        if (srcSize < COPY_THRESHOLD ||
            (src instanceof RandomAccess && dest instanceof RandomAccess)) {
            for (int i=0; i<srcSize; i++)
                dest.set(i, src.get(i));
        } else {
            ListIterator<? super T> di=dest.listIterator();
            ListIterator<? extends T> si=src.listIterator();
            for (int i=0; i<srcSize; i++) {
                di.next();
                di.set(si.next());
            }
        }
    }
```

I know there already exists the same code block, but there was no explanation for what is the reason behind why we can't use methods like `add` on `List`s with wildcards, and that is mainly to protect type safety.

Answer (score 1):

In copy method

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
        int srcSize = src.size();
        if (srcSize > dest.size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Source does not fit in dest");

        if (srcSize < COPY_THRESHOLD ||
            (src instanceof RandomAccess && dest instanceof RandomAccess)) {
            for (int i=0; i<srcSize; i++)
                dest.set(i, src.get(i));
        } else {
            ListIterator<? super T> di=dest.listIterator();
            ListIterator<? extends T> si=src.listIterator();
            for (int i=0; i<srcSize; i++) {
                di.next();
                di.set(si.next());
            }
        }
    }
```

copy replace the value with index from index 0.

```
 public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> des,List<? extends T> scr){
    for(T f : scr){
        des.add(f);
    }
  }
```

in this approach add into tail.